# PowerMock - How to call manipulate the parameters of a mocked method

Tags: java, junit, powermock, easymock

I'm using PowerMock/EasyMock to test a static method in which one of the parameters is a StringBuffer that is appended to by a method in that mocked class.

This is a simplified class to demonstrate.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class ContentChanger
{
    public static int change(StringBuffer sb)
    {
        sb.append( new Date() );
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And here is the unit test...

```
import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ContentChanger.class)
public class ContentChangerTest
{
    @Test
    public void test001()
    {
    // Declare an empty StringBuffer
    StringBuffer var = new StringBuffer();

    // Enable static mocking for the ContentChanger class
    PowerMock.mockStatic( ContentChanger.class );

    // Catch the call and send to test method
    EasyMock.expect(ContentChanger.change( var )).andDelegateTo( test(var) );

    // Replay all mock classes/methods
    PowerMock.replayAll();

    // Call the method to be mocked
    System.out.println( ContentChanger.change( var ) + " = " + var );
    }


    private int test( StringBuffer sb )
    {
        sb.append( "Mocked" );
        return 1;
    }
}
```

What I expect to happen is that the test method is called and the StringBuffer to output..

> 1 = MOCKED

But what is happening is the StringBuffer var is updated before the mocked method is called.

i.e. I get the following...

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call ContentChanger.change(Mocked):
    ContentChanger.change(Mocked): expected: 1, actual: 2
```

Is there a way to invoke another class/method, to change the contents of the parameter when called instead of pre-replay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `test(var)`. `andDelegateTo` expects an Object that will be of the same class/interface as the mock. See http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#verification-creating.

Since you are on a static method, this is not really possible. So the best is to use IAnswer instead. Here is the working code:

```
        EasyMock.expect(ContentChanger.change( var )).andAnswer(new IAnswer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer answer() throws Throwable {
            StringBuffer sb = (StringBuffer) EasyMock.getCurrentArguments()[0];
            sb.append( "Mocked" );
            return 1;
        }
    })
```

Comment: As a comment, I think EasyMock should validate the type passed to andDelegateTo. Also, `actual: 2` seems like a bug.

Comment: I'll comment on my previous comment. It is half a bug. The delegation call ends up calling the static method. Which is why we have the 2. It's hard to explain but let's say it's PowerMock that can't validate what happens in EasyMock and EasyMock not aware that a static method can be mocked